# How to repair pyinstaller error: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pyinstaller

Every time I try to type pyinstaller in cmd, I get this error: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "".

[This is a picture of that problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBKrk.png)

Comment: Follow the path and check if the exe file exist there

Comment: another way to run the exe is to directly click on the file after you follow the path.

Comment: I don't have python.exe in that directory.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and installing again?

Comment: Yes, I moved the python.exe file into that directory and now it says: PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies. Please install pywin32-ctypes.

Answer (score 0):

### I will try to help you with 3 solutions im assuming 1 will work

---

***1. Try to upgrade pyinstaller using***

****`pip python -m pip install --upgrade pyinstaller`****

***2. Try to reinstall pyinstaller again using***

****`pip uninstall pyinstaller` and then `pip install pyinstaller`****

***3. Last ( i think this is the solution ) try to upgrade **pip** using***

**`pip python -m pip install --upgrade pip`**

---

****if the problem isn't fixed yet try to `open a new issue ticket` in pyinstaller github here : https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues****